# site is not accessable on single ip

Tags: router, wordpress, internet, isp, dreamhost

#### OUR SIDE:

The website is hosted by WordPress on DreamHost server. There are not any filters in WordPress and I can't see any IP blocks on Dreamhost server.

#### CLIENT SIDE:

Client has a single internet connection with 3 public IP. There are no firewalls or filters. Routers are reset to default. All the computers are fine.

#### PROBLEM:

Out of these three IP, our website is not accessible from one IP. In fact, not just website, email or anything that is hosted by Dreamhost is not accessible. I can't ping, nslookup, even can't ping IP.

But with the same line with another IP on the same PC works fine. Already contacted ISP. They didn't resolve it. Where might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshoot the problem connection like you would any other network issue. It sounds like you're able to isolate the client to using just the problem connection, so verify that the gateway is properly configured and that it can be pinged. If it can't, the issue is likely a configuration problem either on the client or on the access device for that connection and this problem is likely way beyond the scope of Serverfault. Work with your Network Admin to solve it.

Comment: I am sure that there is no problem on client computer cuz I can open the same site with another connection. And I have not done personally but they(client's IT person) say that he used another IP on the same line, same router and it worked, he swithed different router didn't work.

Comment: I have a feeling that there is a problem with ISP but they already replied that they didn't see any wrong.

Comment: IT person on there have general knowledge on networking Cisco, MikroTik routers, I can be sure that he did all the general troubleshooting.